# Xcode6 freezes on save

Tags: xcode, xcode6.3

XCode 6.3.1 (on OS X Yosemite 10.10.2) freezes with the "spinning wait cursor" 50% of the time I press save.
Google search gave zero (useful/related) results. Have any else seen this weird issue?

Answer (score -1):

First, what do you want to save?!

Second, if you **restarted** Xcode and **rebooted** your Mac and that did not solve it, make sure to **reinstall** Xcode since this appears to be a bug in your version. You can download it from the Mac AppStore or the Developers' MemberCenter.

Hope that helps :)